# Differences between Thread Control Block and Thread Local Storage and which one contains the __stack_chk_guard variable

Tags: linux, glibc, thread-local-storage

I would like to know what the differences between TCB and TLS are. Also in which of the two is the variable __stack_chk_guard?

I looked for a lot of information about it, but I think it confused me even more than I was before.

Some sites report that the variable __stack_chk_guard is in the TCB others report it in the TLS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Some sites report` What sites? How do they report that?

Comment: In this site: https://ctf-wiki.github.io/ctf-wiki/pwn/linux/mitigation/canary/ is reported as follows: "for Linux, the fs register actually points to the TLS structure of the current stack, and fs:0x28 points to stack_guard." Instead in the standard library is says so: /* The stack guard goes into the TCB, so initialize it early.  */

Comment: What is unclear in that description? Yes, if `__stack_chk_guard` is inside "TLS structure" and "TLS structure" is inside "TCB", then ergo `__stack_chk_guard` is inside "TCB".

Comment: if TLS is a programming method, then how can it be a structure?

Comment: I know I am picky about terms (sorry about that!), but honestly "TLS structure" is for me a understandable shortcut for "a block of memory allocated for thread-local storage use". I really fail to see, if you would for example read: `for Linux, the fs register actually points to the memory of the current stack allocated for thread-local use ` would that be understandable to you?

Answer (score 0):

> Differences between Thread Control Block and Thread Local Storage

These are different terms. The differences are clear after reading wikipedia.

[Thread Control Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_control_block) is a block of memory. It is allocated inside the operating system to hold thread specific data.

[Thread Local Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) is a programming method. It consists of using data that are local to the thread.

In C a [*thread-local storage duration*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) is a storage duration of objects that are initialized when thread is started and each thread has it's own distinct object.

> which one contains the __stack_chk_guard variable

A programming method can't "contain", so TLS doesn't "contain" a variable.

Then the answer if `__stack_chk_guard` variable is thread-local depends on the compiler and architecture. With `gcc` we have [`-mstack-protector-guard=guard`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options) compile option, that can be either `-mstack-protector-guard=global`, in which case `__stack_chk_guard` will not be inside TLS, or it can be `-mstack-protector-guard=tls`, in which case.. you guessed it.

> Also in which of the two is the variable __stack_chk_guard?

TCB is a block of memory, and TLS is a programming method. These are different terms, that can't "be" a variable.

> __stack_chk_guard is in the TCB others report it in the TLS.

In a programming slang/jargon, I would say that TLS block means the same as TCB, probably some sites are using these terms like they mean the same (well, because a TLS memory has to be inside TCB anyway).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. however about what you say here `well, because a TLS memory has to be inside TCB anyway` I found [this](https://uclibc.org/docs/tls.pdf) document that would prove otherwise. TCB is in the TLS. I know I'm fussy and I apologize, but I'm writing an important document and I don't want to be inaccurate.